# FileNotFoundException When Uploading File (Non-image) To App

Tags: java, android, file, filenotfoundexception, fileinputstream

I've been trying to allow the user to upload a file (PDF) to my app for eventual upload to my Parse server, but every time I attempt to create a filestream/buffered input stream, I get a FileNotFoundException, claiming that there is 'no such file or directory'. One of my logged file paths appears below:

*/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.parse.starter/files/Eloquent_JavaScript.pdf*

I have no idea as to why it's giving me this bad path. This is my MainActivity (my only activity). I understand that not all files will be stored internally on the phone -- that's why I used certain support methods for my onActivityResult class. I've been struggling to isolate my issue because I haven't been working with files for very long, so things are still relatively new to me. Again, I apologize for all the code. Any assistance is appreciated.

**Intent Method**

```
public void getFile() 
{

     Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.setType("application/pdf");
     intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

     startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

 }
```

**onActivityResult Method**

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        filename = null;
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    Uri uri = data.getData();

                    if (1 > 1) {
                        Toast.makeText(this,"The selected file is too large. Select a new file with size less than 2mb",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        String mimeType = getContentResolver().getType(uri);
                        if (mimeType == null) {
                            String path = getPath(this, uri);
                            if (path == null) {
                                filename = uri.toString().substring(uri.toString().lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                            } else {
                                File file = new File(path);
                                filename = file.getName();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Uri returnUri = data.getData();
                            Cursor returnCursor = getContentResolver().query(returnUri, null, null, null, null);
                            int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                            int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
                            returnCursor.moveToFirst();
                            filename = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex);
                            String size = Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex));
                        }
                        File fileSave = getExternalFilesDir(null);
                        String sourcePath = getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/" + filename;
                        sourcePath = sourcePath.substring(sourcePath.lastIndexOf("data") + 4, sourcePath.length());
                        Log.i("PATH", sourcePath);
                        Log.i("NAME", filename);

                        // create byte array
                        File file = new File(sourcePath);
                        int size = (int) file.length();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
                        try {
                            BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                            buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                            buf.close();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        // byte array created
                }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Here Are Some Support Methods for the onActivityResult method**

```
    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = { column };
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
```

Comment: It may 'seem' accurate, but clearly it isn't. We can't tell you where your file is. Only you know that.

Comment: @EJP While I appreciate the downvote, I'm trying to figure out why it's giving me the incorrect filepath. It's not about the specific file, it's about where my program THINKS the file is. Come on, man, work with me.

Comment: I didn't say anything about downvoting. You've got two of them, and you have zero information about who did it, by design and intent of SO.

Answer (score 0):

All apps (root or not) have a default data directory, which is `/data/data/<package_name>`. By default, the apps databases, settings, and all other data go here. If an app expects huge amounts of data to be stored, or for other reasons wants to "be nice to internal storage", there's a corresponding directory on the SDCard (`Android/data/<package_name>`).

In your code, at this line

```
String sourcePath = getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + "/" + filename;
```

filename is the actual path. `getExternalFilesDir(null).toString()` appends `/storage/emulated/0/` to the start of `sourcePath`. Not all files are from Internal Storage. So remove it.

```
String sourcePath = filename;
```

Comment: No, only the file name is contained in 'filename'. Not the path.